# Android UI very slow

Tags: android, performance, user-interface

I'm creating a simple app that will stream the internet radio station. So when the user clicks the play button I want to show a progress bar (loading circle) until the stream is being played.

I have two Runnables, one to show the progress bar, other to load audio stream and play. This is a progress bar Runnable:

```
private Runnable showProgressBar = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        progBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
};
```

Than on button click:

```
buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Handler show_progress_h = new Handler();
        show_progress_h.post(showProgressBar);
        Handler play_h = new Handler();
        play_h.post(startPlayingThread);
    }
});
```

But... the progress bar loads much to late. It loads when the radio is almost loaded, so you only see it for a blink. Is it possible to show it immediately after the button was clicked? I have no idea what is slowing it down. Should I use something else instead of Handler?

Oh and btw... I also tried both with no handlers, but the response is the same.

Comment: DO it using ASYNCTASK it'll handle your task properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are posting long running task on UI thread immidiatly after showing progressbar:

```
buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Handler show_progress_h = new Handler();
    show_progress_h.post(showProgressBar);
    Handler play_h = new Handler();
    play_h.post(startPlayingThread);//<< issue is here
}
});
```

Instead do something similar to this:

```
buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            Handler show_progress_h = new Handler();
            show_progress_h.post(showProgressBar);
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
                 @Override
                 protected void doInBackground(Void v){
                 // perform long runningtask here that you are performing in 
                 //startPlayingThread
                 } 
           }.execute();
    }
});
```

For more detail check this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html#concurrency_asynchtask

Answer (score 0):

You can use new Thread(your_runnable).start() as an alternative, and try debugging it.